What dependency injection pattern works with shared domain entities using the repository/unit of work pattern
I'm embarking upon a new application framework which will ultimately support many different applications and for each of those applications they will all share a set of common domain entities e.g. Accounts, Contacts, Addresses etc.
For the purposes of this question lets say I have 2 applications Forms and Complaints and both of these applications will have a common shared domain entity called Accounts. Each application will have its own database context and corresponding physical database. I can create a common domain project that defines and configures the Account domain entity and then each application database context can use that so that the common entity is shared between both databases, excellent!
The problems start when I try to implement IAccountRepository this will need access to the database context however, because these domain entities are shared across all databases I can't use ComplaintsDbContext or FormsDbContext directly. I could use the DbContext abstraction but I how can I register this within the dependency injection container allowing some form of dynamic switching between the 2 database contexts ComplaintsDbContext or FormsDbContext.
I feel like there is going to be some pattern I'm not aware of that will help with this?
My repositories will be implemented using .Set() so I have no concerns about having access to set properties on the db context itself as we do not implement any. Hence why I feel that I can inject a DbContext and my repositories will work fine but, how do I get the appropriate database context injected?
Thanks in advance!

I understand that an application never switches between 2 databases. If so, DI wouldn't have to do that either. BTW, don't use an additional repository/UoW pattern. EF already implements it. Superimposing your own layer only adds code and removes flexibility.

Hmmm I don't think there's anything that says an application can't access more than one database, our function app projects for example would almost certainly access multiple databases. I'm aware that EF implements a unit of work but I don't want to couple my MediatR application layer with EF hence why its there.

I don't think there's anything that says... No, there isn't, I'm asking about your applications. You really have to give details on what contexts of a typical application looks like (in essence) and give an example of how one entity causes the conflict you describe. As for the repository pattern, it's impossible to decouple an application from a specific IQueryable implementation. Also, the idea of mediator is that you have vertical slices which is almost the opposite of all this layering we were always told to bake into our applications.

I don't think you should be looking at DI patterns here. The main question is how the application should handle working with multiple databases. Do you wish to access both databases from a single process? Do you wish to edit two database within one transaction? Or do you want to run Accounts as a bounded context/service? And then: expose it via an API, or use a more event-based model using durable queues. Those are the architectural questions you should be investigating. Only after you chose the right architecture, thinking about the right DI patterns starts to make sense.

I think I was maybe trying to solve a problem we didn't have!  The shared entities have been setup with their own DbContext and the appropriate database is assigned to that context at startup depending on the app that's being launched.  I thought I could create the repository like IAccountRepository which works until you introduce MediatR because you lose the typing unless you pass something in the command itself.  Thanks for your help guys it all helped for me to gain some clarity!
